# Can a NuGet package declare a dependency without adding that dependency to the project?

Tags: nuget

I've created a NuGet package that contains some custom MSBuild tasks named *MyCompany.MSBuild*. These tasks have a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json. This means that after my package is installed in a project, [`Newtonsoft.Json.dll` will have to be in the same directory as `MyCompany.MSBuild.dll`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636521/custom-msbuild-task-with-dependencies).

I could easily accomplish this by bundling my own copy of Newtonsoft.Json.dll in my package, but I wonder if there's a better way that means I won't have to update my package whenever a new version of Newtonsoft.Json comes out.

[If I declare *Newtonsoft.Json* as a dependency](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Specifying_Dependencies), NuGet will *install* that package into the project when somebody installs my package, which isn't what I want to have happen.

How can I specify a dependency in my package without having NuGet install it and add project references? Additionally, how can I copy that package's assembly to my own package's folder after it is installed?

Answer (score 2):

A package with a "hidden" dependency is something absolutely undesiderable in my opinion...

I know it's not a real answer but... Have you considered to use JavascriptSerializer instead of Newtonsoft.Json? It's a bit slower but your package will be absolutely self-contained: less pain for you and for your users.